# How can I convert this knockout view model to be Durandal compliant?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, durandal, durandal-2.0

I have a system built on **KnockoutJS** and I am now trying to take advantage of **Durandal**. I have figured out how to make MVC routes play nicely with it and so am now quite comfortable in that respect. However, I am a little bit confused about the view models. I suppose the confusion lies with my ignorance of **RequireJS**. What I am looking for is a simple example for the following sample view model:

The following is a skeleton/example of what is very common in my system and so I would need to know how to make this play nicely with **Durandal**:

```
var SomeModelA = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(0);
    self.name = ko.observable(null);
    //etc

    self.create = function () {
        //etc
    };

    self.edit = function (id) {
        //etc
    };

    self.delete = function (id) {
        //etc
    };

    self.save = function () {
        //etc
    };

    self.cancel = function () {
        //etc
    };
};

var SomeModelB = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(0);
    self.name = ko.observable(null);
    //etc

    self.create = function () {
        //etc
    };

    self.edit = function (id) {
        //etc
    };

    self.delete = function (id) {
        //etc
    };

    self.save = function () {
        //etc
    };

    self.cancel = function () {
        //etc
    };
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.someModelA = new SomeModelA();
    self.someModelB = new SomeModelB();
};

var viewModel;
$(document).ready(function () {
    viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $("#GridA").kendoGrid({
        //etc
    });
    $("#GridB").kendoGrid({
        //etc
    });
});
```

All I need is a really basic example based on the above.

And before anyone mentions it; yes I am aware of **Aurelia** - it's awesome and I will be using it in new projects... But my current system is making heavy use of **Knockout** and therefore it makes sense to go with **Durandal** for now... which may turn out to be a stepping stone towards **Aurelia** later anyway.

**EDIT**

Please note I have tried the following with no success:

**JS:**

```
var SomeModelA = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(null);
};
var SomeModelB = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(null);
};

define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
    return function () {
        var self = this;
        self.modelA = new SomeModelA(),
        self.modelB = new SomeModelB(),

        self.showA = function () {
            alert(this.modelA.name());
        },
        self.showB = function () {
            alert(this.modelB.name());
        }
    };
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<section>
    @Html.TextBox("NameA", null, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "modelA.name" })
    @Html.TextBox("NameB", null, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "modelB.name" })

    <button type="button" data-bind="click: showA" class="btn btn-default">Show A</button>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: showB" class="btn btn-default">Show B</button>
</section>
```

The above does not seem to bind the data correctly. When i change something in the textbox, then click the button, I can see the values are still showing as "NULL". What am I missing here?

Comment: I haven't used Durandal, but I used Require.js+knockout.js. Try to move SomeModelA and SomeModelB definition inside the define block.

Comment: @Maris, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't help...

Comment: But what markup is being generated after `@Html.TextBox(...)` Can you attach the example?

Comment: @Maris: `<input id="NameA" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="NameA" data-bind="modelA.name">
<input id="NameB" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="NameB" data-bind="modelB.name">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually being pretty stupid here; forgetting to tell knockout what to bind to.. in this case, "value". So, the working example is as follows:

**JS:**

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
    var SomeModelA = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.name = ko.observable('testA');
    };
    var SomeModelB = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.name = ko.observable('testB');
    };

    var vm = {
        modelA: new SomeModelA(),
        modelB: new SomeModelB(),

        showA: function () {
            alert(this.modelA.name());
        },
        showB: function () {
            alert(this.modelB.name());
        }
    };
    return vm;
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<section>
    @Html.TextBox("NameA", null, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: modelA.name" })
    @Html.TextBox("NameB", null, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: modelB.name" })

    <button type="button" data-bind="click: showA" class="btn btn-default">Show A</button>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: showB" class="btn btn-default">Show B</button>
</section>
```